# LinearLayout.getwidth is zero when outside Runnable

Tags: java, android

I tried to get the width of a LinearLayout.

Here is the code of the MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        BoardClass board;
        private int widthareagame;
       @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       final LinearLayout  gamearea;
        ImageView im1 ;
        Button abutton;
        abutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonnew);
        gamearea = ( LinearLayout)  findViewById(R.id.boardarea);
        gamearea.post(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                widthareagame = gamearea.getWidth();
            }
        });

        board = new BoardClass(this,widthareagame);
        gamearea.addView(board);
    }
```

The value of `widthareagame` at `new BoardClass(this,widthareagame);` is still Zero.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please post the xml too?

Comment: Move those last two lines in `onCreate()` into the `run()` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is because post method call queued the setting of `widthareagame` where as your view is rendering.You didn't guarantee the order of execution.

You have to make sure the statements inside the run method execute first and then `new Board(..` is invoked.For that you can do something like this

```
final AtomicBoolean done = new AtomicBoolean(false);
run(){
//inside run method
done.set(true);
notify();
}
```

then do something like this

```
synchronized(task) {
            while(!done.get()) {
                task.wait();
            }
   new Board(..

        }
where task is your runnable task defined something like this
final Runnable task = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
```

Comment: There is no other thread involved here. The `Runnable` is being posted to the same thread. It just gets queued after a bunch of other stuff, which causes it to run after the `View` gets laid out.

Comment: you have to wait for run to execute.Can you please try out the way mentioned in answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#post(java.lang.Runnable)) says about `View#post()`:

> Causes the Runnable to be added to the message queue. The runnable
>   will be run on the user interface thread.

Your task, of modifying the value of `widthareagame` variable, has been pushed to the message queue of the view. It doesn't guarantee that it will get executed at the very same instance. The control then proceeds to the next line, where you still get the unmodified value.

You can try something like this, to ensure that you are able to use the modified value:

```
gamearea.post(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                widthareagame = gamearea.getWidth();
                board = new BoardClass(this,widthareagame);
                gamearea.addView(board);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is zero is because within the onCreate the LinearLayout has not been measured yet. 
And the reason it only works when within the Runnable is because since this one has been posted then it will run on the next execution cycle, which is after the onCreate and the rest of the Activity lifecycle methods (onStart, onResume, etc.) and even onAttachedToWindow have been called, at which point will be already measured and give the correct size.

Said all that, a safer way to get your layout metrics with certainty would be to listen when the layout state changes.

```
gamearea.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        // Remove the listener here unless you want to get this callback for
        // "every" layout pass, which can get you into an infinite loop if you
        // modify the layout from within this method
        gamearea.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

        // A this point you can get the width and height
        widthareagame = gamearea.getWidth();
    }
});
```